# Shiny image upload

Tags: r, shiny

Not certain why this simple code is not working. The goal is to upload an image from a device and view as shiny output. I keep getting an error, 
*****Error: invalid filename argument*****

```
library(jpeg)
library(shiny)
library(magick)
library(magrittr)




  ui <- fluidPage(

#-------------------------------------Header Panel--------------------------------------------------#

titlePanel('Invoice Recognition & Interpretation -IRI'),

#--------------------------------Sidebar : Image Upload---------------------------------------------#
sidebarLayout(

  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput(inputId = "file1", 
              label = "Upload Invoice",
             accept = c('image/png', 'image/jpeg','image/jpg')
    ),

    tags$hr()

  ),


  mainPanel( 

  imageOutput(outputId = "Invoice")

    )
)
)


server <- function(input, output) {

re1<-reactive({ input$file1})

output$Invoice<-renderImage({re1()})

 }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most of the way there, however, you need to understand that your `fileInput` returns a data frame and not just the *path*. Also, the `renderImage` is similar to an `<img>` and you need to assign the `src`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel('Invoice Recognition & Interpretation -IRI'),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput(
        inputId = "file1",
        label = "Upload Invoice",
        accept = c('image/png', 'image/jpeg','image/jpg')
      ),
      tags$hr()
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("filename"),
      imageOutput(outputId = "Invoice")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  re1 <- reactive({gsub("\\\\", "/", input$file1$datapath)})

  output$Invoice <- renderImage({list(src = re1())})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```